# Map colors in colorbar in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the code below to generate 3d surface plots. I would like the color to represent the value of the radius. How do I draw the corresponding colorbar?

I believe the problem is that I am using `facecolors` while making a surface plot. So I need to make the colorbar according to this facecolors.

I understand that I have to map these colors to the colorbar, it's just that I don't know how.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sph2cart(theta, phi, radius):
    x_cart = radius * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
    y_cart = radius * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
    z_cart = radius * np.cos(theta)
    return np.array([x_cart, y_cart, z_cart])

def antenna_plot_3D(mod_F, T, P):
    [x, y, z] = sph2cart(T, P, mod_F)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
    p_surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1, 
                             linewidth=0, antialiased=True, 
                             facecolors=cm.jet(np.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)))
    ax.set_zlabel('Z axis', fontsize=15)
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis', fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis', fontsize=15)
    plt.savefig('3d_pattern.png')
    plt.show()

x = 300
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi, num=x)
p = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, num=x)
[T,P] = np.meshgrid(t,p)
mod_F = np.sin(T) * np.cos(P)
antenna_plot_3D(mod_F, T, P)
```

I want the surface to be colored and the colors should represent the radius.

Comment: I've tried that, it gives the following error.
    raise RuntimeError('No mappable was found to use for colorbar '
RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).

Comment: I'm not gonna mess with all that: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See the problem is, I am `facecolors` while making the surface plot. Now I need to make the colorbar according to this `facecolors`. I understand that I have to map these colors to the colorbar, its just that I don't know how.

Comment: OK, after heavily editing your question, matplotlib (v1.4.1) is telling me that `'3d'` is an invalid projection. So now you *really* need to fix this code to make it runnable if you want help.

Comment: @PaulH is very right, your code is already broken without even dealing with the colorbar (i.e. *add your imports* ... `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D` will fix Paul's '3d' problem but then you're still missing `cm`).  See Paul's comment above re: MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following did the task

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
p_surf=ax.plot_surface(x,y,z,rstride=1,cstride=1,linewidth=0,antialiased=True,facecolors=cm.jet(np.sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)))
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.jet)
m.set_array(x*x + y*y + z*z)
plt.colorbar(m)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant add this in comment so posting it as a answer.
you should add this to your import according to #Ajean and @PaulH.Then instead of facecolors try cmap.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D


def sph2cart(theta, phi, radius):
    x_cart = radius * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
    y_cart = radius * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
    z_cart = radius * np.cos(theta)
    return np.array([x_cart, y_cart, z_cart])


def antenna_plot_3D(mod_F, T, P):
    [x, y, z] = sph2cart(T, P, mod_F)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
    p_surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                         linewidth=0, antialiased=True,
                         cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z axis', fontsize=15)
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis', fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis', fontsize=15)
    fig.colorbar(p_surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
    plt.savefig('3d_pattern.png')
    plt.show()

x = 300
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi, num=x)
p = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, num=x)
[T,P] = np.meshgrid(t,p)
mod_F = np.sin(T) * np.cos(P)
antenna_plot_3D(mod_F, T, P)
plt.show()
```

[image: result plot]

Comment: I want to color the surface according to the value of the radius.

Comment: To create colors based on radius you have to create a colour array with index of x,y and some function to fill a colour into that array based on a criteria. The problem is you are passing x, y and radius as separate arrays, they are not indexed. For eg if I decide a color for a particular radius, I should be able to assign that particular color to corresponding x,y.